# Cron job unable to start

Tags: shell, cron

I have a cron job

```
* * * * * /home/username/start.sh that runs every minutes
```

`start.sh` contents:

```
touch /home/username/test.txt
firefox
```

The cron job changes the timestamp of `test.txt` but is unable to open `firefox`. I have tried  setting up env variables, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point to the absolute path of `firefox`, which you can find using `which firefox` as a normal user. The value could for example be `/usr/bin/firefox`.

Also, `firefox` is a GUI program, but cron jobs run in the background, and have no idea about X, so you can't start a new Firefox client in this way. For example, consider if you have two desktop logins to the same machine, via the network and locally. Where should Firefox show up when run from `cron`? It can't show up in both places without a more complex setup such as `rdesktop`. You *can* run it on a given display if you add that to the environment, like this (untested):

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
/usr/bin/firefox
```

But Firefox will protest after running it the first time that it's already running, so this is only going to work if you close the window every minute.

*What are you trying to accomplish?*

If you are trying to [check that a web server is running](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#Starting_a_.22daemon.22_and_checking_whether_it_started_successfully), you can use a shell tool like `wget` or `curl` (one of which is very likely installed already) to prod it. If you want to do testing (and you do if you want to develop good software), have a look into frameworks like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit).

Comment: Yeah.I tried this.It doesnt work.If I manually run start.sh the firefox opens but not with cronjob

Comment: Actually I have written a script that reads node process pid from a file and checks if that pid is running and if not it starts a node process with nohup and writes the new pid to the file.I will run this script say every 5 mins with cronjob.Now I cannot run this script with cronjob.SO thought might try something with cron job to test the cronjob and encountered this one.

Comment: Thanks for answer :) I have a command ps -ef | grep $pidd | grep -v grep inside the shell script it runs fine.
But this statement doesnt run 
if ps -ef | grep $pidd | grep -v grep ; then